# Can you specify a local address on a JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc

We are trying to connect to a SQL Server database from a box that has multiple addresses assigned to it. Can I specify what address JDBC chooses to make the connection with like you can when creating a socket connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact you can even have a JDBC driver that *is* the database (such as Embedded Derby)